# Swift UiTableView not reloading search results

Tags: swift, xcode

I am having a weird issue where for some reason my UITableView is not being reloading after performing a search. The console prints out the correctly filtered data, but the table simply doesn't change. I have never encountered this issue, so I first attempted the solutions which naturally came to mind:

1. Tried `tableView.reloadData()` in the Main Queue
2. Quit Xcode, clean build, reinstall
3. Cleared out the derived data dir

I have found several similar issue in SO, but all of the solutions I've seen are things I've tried, mainly reloading tableview in main queue.

Hoping maybe I just simply have an issue in my code or something I'm missing.

I am running Xcode 8.3.3

```
import UIKit

class CategoriesViewController: UIViewController {

var isFiltering = false
var location = Location()
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
var categoriesSearchResults = [Category]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.allowsSelection = true
    tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CategoryTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier:"CategoryTableViewCell");
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
    searchBar.delegate = self
}


extension CategoriesViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("HI")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if isFiltering {
        return self.categoriesSearchResults.count
    }

    return self.location.categories.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    if let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CategoryTableViewCell {
        var category: Category
        if isFiltering {
            category = self.categoriesSearchResults[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            category = self.location.categories[indexPath.row]
        }
        cell.name.text = category.name
        cell.status.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        cell.status.text = "Not Verified"
    }

    return cell
}
}

extension CategoriesViewController : UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool{
    return self.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.isFiltering = true
    self.categoriesSearchResults.removeAll()
    tableView.reloadData()
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBarIsEmpty() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.isFiltering = false
    } else {
        self.isFiltering = true
        self.categoriesSearchResults = self.location.categories.filter({ (category: Category) -> Bool in
            return category.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        })
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

and my custom table view cell:

```
import UIKit

class CategoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var status: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.name.text   = ""
    self.status.text = ""
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: Might also be worth mentioning, when I am actively searching, the function `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is not called??

Comment: In `tableView(_ tableView:cellForRowAt:)` You pass the `if isFiltering{}else{}` in the if or in the else?

Comment: @Larme in not really following your question? If I add `print` into the if and the else I see the correct data. Literally the only issue is the tableview isn't showing the correct data. Super weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of `if let` nests in its scope. In your code you are always returning `let cell = UITableViewCell()`. Try returning it inside the `if let` :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    if let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CategoryTableViewCell {
        var category: Category
        if isFiltering {
            category = self.categoriesSearchResults[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            category = self.location.categories[indexPath.row]
        }
        cell.name.text = category.name
        cell.status.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        cell.status.text = "Not Verified"

        /// RETURN CELL HERE
        return cell

    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Wow, cannot believe I didn't catch that. Thank you very much for the help, this solved my issue.

Comment: Glad it helped :)